# iPhone: Block One Website & Only One Website

Tags: iphone, safari, google-chrome

I need a way to block one website on my iPhone while leaving "adult content" available.

I'm very familiar with the **block adult content** restriction on the iPhone, but the amount of sites this feature blocks is ridiculous. It blocks anything that mentions men's/women's health and even websites crucial to my university's student life. (And no, I can't just white-list them because they all have different domain trees & it blocks the brief login page that occurs before I complete said login).

I've also looked at apps such as **Zero Willpower**, but these seem to only work with safari. (I use chrome).

Is there any way to allow access to all websites and only block one? (Perhaps a way to white-list all websites under the "adult content" banner and then blacklist the target site).

Comment: As this is about chrome we can’t really help

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, but it needs some technical skills and some money. Get yourself a private server, set up a VPN server on it, and block the IP address for the website from being accessed through the VPN. Then use Apple Configurator to turn your phone into a managed device and force it to use your private VPN at all times.

Comment: I must admit that I don't have the technical skills to do this. Also, I may be mistaken, but it seems like this solution wouldn't work if you don't have constant access to the VPN server. So using an alternate wi-fi or cellular data would bypass it.

Comment: @PythonCheese That’s why you have to use Apple Configurator to configure the phone so that it has to use the VPN at all times.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/218851/how-to-enable-always-on-vpn-on-an-iphone-or-ipad/

Answer (score 0):

You could use an app that creates a VPN-Network only on your local device. An app which can do this and I can recommend is AdGuard Pro (https://adguard.com/en/adguard-ios-pro/overview.html). With this app you can block a particular website or whole list of websites entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Many content blockers for Safari have this feature. I use [1Blocker Legacy](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/legacy/id1025729002) which is entirely free (gratis) and lets you write custom rules under "Block URLs". You can turn off all the other block sets it provides. I'm using this with iOS 13.5; I'm not sure whether it works with the latest iOS 14.